# Having difficulty understanding how function works

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I've written a function in python to see If i know what I'm doing but unfortunately I'm not. I thought my defined `arg` variable will hold a number and multiply each of the numbers which `*args` variable holds and print it all at a time. But, it is giving me the first result only.

This is what I've written:

```
def res_info(arg,*args):
   for var in args:
    return var*arg

print(res_info(2,70,60,50))
```

Having:

```
140
```

Expected:

```
140
120
100
```

I don't understand why I'm not getting all the results. Thanks for taking a look into it.

Comment: return will always end(?) the function; the function call stops at 70*2

Comment: `return` will end the function at the first iteration, so you'll end up with 140 as result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right path. The problem you had was due to your use of the `return` statement. Use [`yield`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement) instead.

```
>>> def res_info(arg,*args): 
        for var in args: 
            yield var*arg 

>>> list(res_info(2,70,60,50))
=> [140, 120, 100]
```

So, what was happening was, even though your logic was correct, since there was a **`return` statement in the loop**, your loop hence was *never fully executed* and your program scope would come out on the first iteration of the loop itself (ie, when `var = 70`).

Using `yield`, solved the problem as it returns a `Generator object` after all calculations, and hence does not exit the loop like return does.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity along with `yield` function.

Comment: @shayan : sure. Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

```
def res_info(arg,*args):
    result = []
    for var in args:
        result.append(var*arg)
    return result

print(res_info(2,70,60,50))
```

Comment: Thanks Avijit Dasgupta, for your answer. It produces what I expected. +1 for this.

Comment: @shayan This isn't list comprehension